# How can one tell which user started this program?

Tags: c, linux, process

I know `ps` command can see this , but given the pid ,  how can one know which user started that program ? I see a `loginuid` in /proc/[pid]/ , but that seems to be a complemental-code of the real uid , not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `status` ?

```
cnicutar@lemon:/proc/self$ cat status
Name:   bash
State:  S (sleeping)
#....
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Gid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
```

There are 4 UIDs: Real, effective, saved set, and file system. It's all described in [`proc(5)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html).

Comment: And .. where to find document about this , e.g fields in `status` , `stat` ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want ONLY the user and you are aware of the PID you can use `ps` and `awk` like this:

`ps auxf | awk  NR!=1 | awk  '{print $1" "$2}' | grep`pid`| awk '{print $1}'`

I will break down the command so you can get a better idea of the process.

As you probably know, the first line of `ps` shows the header, that is why we use `awk NR!=1`  to exclude the header from the obtained output.

Since we need only the `PID` and the `User` we can get rid of the other columns by selecting only the first two with `awk '{print $1" "$2}'`.

Using simple `grep` you can find the line you need, filtering by the process id: `grep 123`.

And finally we select only the first column, which is the user: `awk '{print $1}'`